# Handle both unique combination and unique fields at the same time in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, unique, unique-constraint

I have the following table, where I have two fields, both are unique and also their combination is unique.

```
create table mapping
(
    user_id                       uuid                      unique not null,
    profile_id                    uuid                      unique not null,
    constraint user_id_profile_id_unique_constraint
        unique (user_id, profile_id)
);
```

My goal is to trigger different constraints when inserting an already existing combination and when inserting a new combination. An already known combination should be a no-op in my application, however, inserting a new combination of known ids, should return an error on the other hand.

```
My goal for example:
Insert (1, 1) -> no error
Insert (1, 1) -> user_id_unique constraint triggered
Insert (1, 2) -> user_id_profile_id_unique_constraint
```

In this current setup, the same constraint is being triggered for both cases (`user_id_unique`).

Comment: You have a logic problem there. You are saying user_id is unique and profile_id is unique. If that were true, then user_id, profile_id would naturally be unique. You shouldn't able to have 1,2 when you have 1,1.

Comment: When user_id must be unique on it's own, there is no point in creating a second unique constraint using this column again. It doesn't matter if you add other columns, when user_id isn't unique, the new record will be rejected anyway.

Comment: Looking at your table, it smells like it is a bridging table for a many-to-many relation (users >-< profiles). If that is true, all you need is the constraint user_id_profile_id_unique_constraint. It wouldn't make any sense to make user_id or profile_id unique in a many-to-many bridging table.